# Нужно, чтобы не выводило повторно последнюю строку

Tags: c++, циклы, for

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    int N,j,k,i;
    j = 0;
    k = 1;
    cout << "Введите число N" << endl;
    cin >> N;//конечное число
    for (i = 1; i < (N + 1);i++)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
        j++;
        if (j >= k)
        {
            cout << endl;
            j = 0;
            k++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
```

При, например, N=3 выводит:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Нужно, чтобы выводило строку 1 2 3 1 раз. Как переделать программу? Использовать можно только for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, что у вас накручено...

Вы хотите это?

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= i+1; ++j) cout << j << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```